# JQuery Mobile PhoneGap app has strange behaviour when onclick event is triggered

Tags: android, ios, html, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I am developing an instruction app for a product. The opening screen of the app is a page with all the different models of the product. When a user clicks one, they are brought to a screen with an image of the product, that is mapped using an image map so the user can click on different buttons to see what they do. From there, they can view instructions on using the product.

The strange behaviour I'm experiencing is most noticeable with the iOS app built using PG Build, though it does exist on the Android app also. When the model is selected, there is a big delay between that and when the image map loads - which in itself is tolerable. The problem is that while waiting, the home page's list of models is sort of half displayed. I have created some crude drawings using MS Paint to replicate what this looks like when it is happening:

[image: home-screen]

Then we click on Product Model 1, say, and while it should go directly to this image with the image map:

[image: imagemap]

it instead shows this for a second or two before moving on:

[image: !loading]

The following is an example of the code used to get from the product list to the image map:

```
               <li data-theme="a" data-next="#model1">
                    <a href="#model1" data-transition="none" data-theme="a" onclick="setMapImages();">
                       <img id="image1" src="image.png">
                           <span class = "class1">
                            Product Model 1
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
```

The image map used to be called from an onclick later in the app, and no such problems were experienced. It's only since I've moved it to the first page that it's started acting up. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to get a jsfiddle reproducing the issue?

Comment: I'll have a go later - although when I run in a desktop browser before deploying it to devices, there is literally no lag at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's just jQuery Mobile taking a moment to build the image map. jQM is not ideal for PhoneGap.

Pre-build the the image maps so jQM doesn't have to do it on the fly.

And look around for other frameworks as this is what you will get when doing a lot of image manipulation stuff with jQM and PG.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was just hoping you could tell me how to go about prebuilding the image maps as you suggested?

Comment: When you click the item does it dynamically build the image map or has the image map been built already on another page? You saying the app is for "a" product, which suggests there will be limited maps - this doesn't sound like an expandable, extensible app. In that case why not build the image maps on pages and navigate to the pages when the item is touched. That way they already "exist" - they have been pre-built before you go to them. The problem with jQM on mobiles with PG is there are a lot of things which will slow it down.

Comment: You're right - it is limited, there are not too many maps. The thing is, I am navigating to the pages via the href in the code in the OP; however, I'm still using the onclick event to actually call the JQuery function that's displaying the points. How can this go elsewhere?

Comment: Are you building the map with jQuery/Javascript or is it a normal HTML map? If you have the page already build with a HTML map before you navigate to it it will be fine. I don't understand the role of your setMapImages() function.

Comment: I have inherited this code from a colleague but from what I can see, the use of a jquery plugin "rwdImageMaps" requires that jquery function to be in there - this plugin allows for dynamic screen size changes, therefore not affecting the mappings when the screen size is different. The image maps themselves are regular html alright. Do you think that function could be an issue? This is a very frustrating issue especially as it is holding up a release. There just doesn't seem to be anything inherently wrong with the way this is being done!

Comment: Yes, I think it is that function. Run the function for each page and image BEFORE you go to the page. Do not run for the first time when the user touches the button. What I think is happening (based on my work with exactly the same setup) is that rendering takes time on mobiles the framework isn't really made of PGB if we're begin honest.

Comment: The problem here is how can I do this - the function is in a div, so onclick is the best way to run it as onload is not available. Running the function in the onload of the body neither makes sense nor works. Is there any other way to run it outside of an event?

Comment: Why is onload unavailable? And if you're using jQM you can call initialisation functions straight after document ready.

Comment: The function is being called inside the <div> tag (there are a lot of <div>s), which onload is not available for. I've tried a lot of things - a lot of moving around, dummy functions, dummy pages, but nothing seems to work. I also actually just removed pieces of code at random, and without calling setImageMaps() it still took an age to load. It could be the case that it's just like that and nothing I do will help this issue. Thanks for all your help though, Subjective Effect. You gave me new avenues to go down!

Comment: Post the function, lets see what it does.